# How to provide a password for PostgreSQL's createdb non-interactively?

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, phing

I have a task in phing where before tests I drop the database if exists and create it. This is run on Jenkins. 
I want to do it with createdb like this:

```
<exec command="createdb my_database" />
```

The thing is that the createdb is asking me to authenticate and adding -Umy_user parameter is not a problem - the issue is that I cannot specify a password in the createdb command. And I don't want to create a role for the system user ("jenkins" in this case). Is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`createdb` will use the [PGPASSWORD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) environment variable if it's set, that's one simple way of providing a password in non-interactive runs.

Another option would be to set up a [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file in the home directory of the unix user launching the `createdb`.

Comment: With .pgpass, I initially tried entering a line specifying the name of the database I wanted to create. However, I still got the password prompt on `createdb`. Seems like the database name has to be `*`.

Comment: What will be used for username, if I use `PGPASSWORD` var? Will the username default to `root`?

Comment: @JamesWierzba: the db username defaults to the OS username.

Comment: Can you add an example how to do with .pgpass? I've .pgpass set up and properly working with `psql`, but it doesn't work with `createdb`.