# Postgres createdb run from php exec

Tags: php, postgresql, command-line

I have an install script that can create a db, with
(sql ddl)`create database if not exist`.
Since Postgres works differently the script doesn't work.
So I build a special case for Postgres and used the
(commandline) `createdb -U ...` command for generating a database.
It works so far, but Postgres requests the password a second time.

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351078/how-to-provide-a-password-for-postgresqls-createdb-non-interactively) i found out that
I can provide the password with the var PGPASSWORD
Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122742/execute-two-shell-commands-in-single-exec-php-statement) i came up with a solution:
(php)

```php
exec(' set PGPASSWORD=$password && createdb -U "$username" -h "$host" "$dbname" ')
```

(simplified escapes)

but this returns an error:
*createdb: could not connect with template1: FATAL:  Password authentication for user »postgres« failed (translated)*

I am not familiar with commandline and its characteristics ->
I am not sure if I did a grave unnoticed misstake there, i am sorry if i did

I will implement now a version where Postgres asks the user a second time,
but it would be cool if you find a solution where the user doesn't have to type password twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use an operating system command? You can do the same thing with SQL: Simply connect to the `postgres` database (or any other database) and run

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname
```

Comment: As far as i know: one can only connect to an existing database with Postgres, when the sql 'create database' is already done

Comment: Right, you have to connect to a different, already existing, database. Typically `postgres`, like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I would require the db admin to leave the default database undeleted, if i am doing this, and the script would fail if the postgres default db would be deleted or the user has no rights for the default db: => this is a dirty way

Comment: What you don't realize is that `createdb` does the same thing under the hood: it connects to `postgres`, if that doesn't exist, to `template1`, and runs `CREATE DATABASE`. So if a SQL is more convenient for you than a shell script, you might as well do that instead.